# How can I move a local commit to after all commits in a git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-rewrite-history

Here's my situation. I've been working on a feature and made a local commit. I carried on working. Meanwhile, a colleague pushed changes that I need. Some of those changes are in the same files I'm working on.

I currently have some code I'll need to stash before I pull from origin.
Is there a way to pull the code so my colleagues code exists before my last local commit in the commit history?
I know for a fact that my local commit is older than the ones I'm going to pull.
I'm going to end up with something like this:

`older commits -> my commit -> origin commit 1 -> origin commit 2 -> popped stash`

But what I want is:

`older commits -> origin commit 1 -> origin commit 2 -> my commit -> popped stash`

The only way I can see how to do this is to undo my local commit, stash the whole lot, then pull then pop the stash. Is there a way to do this that will maintain my old commit?

I just saw there is a tag here for `git-rewrite-history`, so it might be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undoing and re-applying a series of commits is called a `rebase`. To pull in changes and `rebase` instead of `merge` them you can use the `--rebase` option:

```
git stash
git pull --rebase origin master
git stash pop
```

Comment: dammit! I knew this! I just forgot somehow. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use git `cherry-pick` concept:

First copy the commit-hash of `commit-hash-before-my-commit`, `my-commit`, `original-commit-1`, `original-commit-2` from `git log` output.

```
$ git log                 # First copy the commit hashes

$ git checkout -b b1      # create a new branch b1 (just for experiment)

$ git reset --hard <commit-hash-before-my-commit>

$ git cherry-pick <original-commit-1>
$ git cherry-pick <original-commit-2>
$ git cherry-pick <my-commit>
$ git stash pop
```

Now, `git log` should show you the commit history as you want.